# VBA Maze Find path

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the path of maze in vba, here is the photo of the maze,the red is the path and the black is the wall,it should generate a path to green. I Try to use BFS in this problem.Here is the code.
Please Help me! 
Most Time I Try this code it return fail
[image]

```
sub FindPath()
    Dim currentRow, currentCol As Integer
    Dim nextRow, nextCol As Integer
    Dim isEnd As Boolean
    Dim visted As Object
    Set visted = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim Tovisted As Object
    Set Tovisted = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") 
    Dim temstore As Variant
    currentRow = 2 currentCol = 2 ' TODO: Check whether the source location is dead block

    If isSafeToMove(currentRow + 1, currentCol) = False And IsSafeToMove(currentRow, currentCol + 1) = False Then

         Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
         MsgBox "No Solution"

    Else
         currentRow = 2
         currentCol = 2

         nextRow = 2
         nextCol = 2

         isEnd = False
     ' TODO: check whether reach the destination yet and the game is not
     '       end yet
        While isEnd = False
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 0 To visted.count - 1
                If currentRow & currentCol <> visted(i) Then

                    Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    visted.Add currentRow & currentCol

                    If currentRow = 5 And currentCol = 5 Then

                       isEnd = True
                       Cells(5, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

                    ElseIf isSafeToMove(currentRow + 1, currentCol) = True Then

                        Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        currentRow = currentRow + 1
                        Tovisted.Add currentRow & currentCol

                    ElseIf isSafeToMove(currentRow, currentCol + 1) = True Then
                        Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                        currentCol = currentCol + 1
                        Tovisted.Add currentRow & currentCol
                    End If
                End If

            Next i

            If Tovisted.count > 0 Then

                Tovisted(Tovisted.count - 1) = temstore
                currentRow = Left(temstore, 1)
                currentCol = Right(temstore, 1)

            Else

                MsgBox "Fail"
                isEnd = True

            End If
        Wend 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: What is BFS? Breadth-first search algorithm? Did you try to debug your code and narrow down the issue? Note that it is much easier to work with cell values then with colors. • Is this some kind of homework? Or what is the purpose of it?

Comment: `Dim currentRow, currentCol As Integer` is not the same as `Dim currentRow As Integer, currentCol As Integer`. What you wrote is actually equivalent to `Dim currentRow As Variant, currentCol As Integer`

Comment: You didn't include the code for `isSafeToMove`... that seems like an important thing to include.

Comment: If you are asking for help with implementing a specific algorithm, please explain what your algorithm is, and what the problem you are encountering is.  If you need an algorithm from scratch, then you could always try using a flood-fill algorithm with (Starting position is `0`.  `FIND` all `0`s, fill surrounding blank spaces with `1`.  `FIND` all `1`s, fill surrounding blank spaces with `2`, `FIND` all `2`s, fill surrounding blank spaces with `3`...  repeat until there are no more blank spaces.  Start at the Goal, and count down until you reach the start.)

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the following maze with start at B2 and goal at M9:

[image]

The following pseudo code was used to implement the *[Breadth-first search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)*

```js
BFS(start_node, goal_node) {
 for(all nodes i) visited[i] = false; // no nodes are visited in the beginning
 queue.push(start_node);              // begin with start node
 visited[start_node] = true;
 while(! queue.empty() ) {            // as long as queue is not empty
  node = queue.pop();                 // take first element of the queue
  if(node == goal_node) {
   return true;                       // test if goal node is found
  }
  foreach(child in expand(node)) {    // all following nodes, …
   if(visited[child] == false) {      // … which are not visited yet …
    queue.push(child);                // … are added to the queue …
    visited[child] = true;            // … and marked as visited
   }
  }
 }
 return false;                        // goal node cannot be reached
}
```

My implementation of the BFS to find the goal cell of the maze:

```
Public Sub BFS(ByVal StartNode As Range, ByVal GoalNode As Range)
    Dim Queue As Object
    Set Queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim VisitedNodes As Collection
    Set VisitedNodes = New Collection  'no nodes are visited yet

    Queue.Add StartNode  'begin with start node
    VisitedNodes.Add StartNode.Address(False, False), StartNode.Address(False, False)

    Do While Queue.Count > 0  'as long as queue is not empty
        Dim Node As Range 
        Set Node = Queue(0)   'take first element of the queue
        Queue.RemoveAt 0

        If Node.Address = GoalNode.Address Then  'test if goal node is found
            MsgBox "Goal found"

            'Backtracing from goal to start to find the path
            Dim BackNode As String
            BackNode = Node.Address(False, False)
            Do
                Range(BackNode).Value = "•"
                BackNode = VisitedNodes.Item(BackNode)
            Loop While BackNode <> StartNode.Address(False, False)

            StartNode.Value = "S"
            GoalNode.Value = "G"

            Exit Sub

        Else   'all following nodes, …

            Dim Child As Range
            For Each Child In Union(Node.Offset(0, -1), Node.Offset(-1, 0), Node.Offset(0, 1), Node.Offset(1, 0)).Cells ' … which are adjacent cells (no diagonal cells, just left, top, right, bottom) …
                If Child.Interior.Color <> vbBlack Then  '… which are no maze borders …
                    If Not ExistsInCollection(VisitedNodes, Child.Address(False, False)) Then   '… which are not visited yet …
                        Queue.Add Child  '… are added to the queue …
                        VisitedNodes.Add Node.Address(False, False), Child.Address(False, False)  '… and marked as visited
                    End If
                End If
            Next Child

        End If
    Loop

    MsgBox "Goal cannot be found."  'goal node cannot be reached
End Sub


'function to test if a key exists in a collection
Public Function ExistsInCollection(Col As Collection, Key As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo err
    ExistsInCollection = True
    IsObject Col.Item(Key)
    Exit Function
err:
    ExistsInCollection = False
End Function
```

And you start the BFS with

```
BFS StartNode:=Range("B2"), GoalNode:=Range("M9")
```

You will get the following result:

[image]

---

Some notes:

- The maze must be built by coloring cells black.
- The maze needs to have a complete black border to fence the algorithm. Otherwise it will run crazy at the entire sheet's cells.
- The BFS usually just tells you if the goal can be reached or not. To get the path from start to goal I added the backtracing part which goes the shortest path backwards.